# Secure requests in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angular and i'm using a 3rd party hotel Api to make a live booking request.

The Api says send all request values within the POST body as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Angular form**

Should I use `$httpParamSerializer` or

```
$http.post(url, data,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
.success(function(response) {
     // your code...
 });
```

I have also read that a standard $http request will just send it as default `json` anyway and is not needed?

What is most secure way for sending from data?